# moving image can't go outside the window DOM

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm creating a script in javascript with 4 buttons to control the movement of an image, the user can move the image to the top, to the bottom, to the left and to the right, but the image can't go outside the window, should maintain inside, but I don't know how to keep it inside. Imaging the ball from the old vintage pin pon game that the ball keep inside the window DOM.

here is the html code:

```
<img class="c1" id="imagen" src="https://media.sproutsocial.com/uploads/2017/02/10x-featured-social-media-image-size.png"/>

<input type="button" value="Arriba" onclick="MoverArriba();" />
<input type="button" value="Abajo" onclick="MoverAbajo();" />
<input type="button" value="Derecha" onclick="MoverDerecha();" />
<input type="button" value="Izquierda" onclick="MoverIzquierda();" />
```

and here is the javascript code:

```
var birdX = 0;

        function MoverArriba() {
            var bird = document.getElementById("imagen");

            birdX -= 1;
            bird.style.transform = "translateY(" + birdX + "px)";

        }

        function MoverAbajo() {
            var bird = document.getElementById("imagen");
    alert("hello");

            birdX += 1;
            bird.style.transform = "translateY(" + birdX + "px)";
    alert("hello2");

        }

        function MoverDerecha() {
            var bird = document.getElementById("imagen");

            birdX += 1;
            bird.style.transform = "translateX(" + birdX + "px)";

        }

        function MoverIzquierda() {
            var bird = document.getElementById("imagen");

            birdX -= 1;

            bird.style.transform = "translateX(" + birdX + "px)";

        }
```

Fiiddle -> https://jsfiddle.net/7vyokgup/1/

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd do this... with math! :D Give the image an absolute position with left and top set to 0; this will help you a lot later, since all your numbers will be relative to (0,0).

When you move left or up, just make sure the value never goes below 0; that's the easy part. The harder part is moving right and down. You need to make sure the x and y don't go beyond the width and height of the screen. Luckily, there are some properties we can use for this! `document.body.clientWidth` and `document.body.clientHeight` will return the width and height (respectively) of the window. So when moving right or down, just ensure the values don't grow larger than the width or height of the window -- minus the width and height of the image, of course, since the position is from the top-left :)